# Django Error Not Found: /NONE in server log

Tags: django-views, django-templates

Using Django, i am passing few list to be displayed on Index page. As such it is working, but i am getting following error in the log. I believe it is an issue but can't find the rootcause. Can someone please help? I have provided required codes i am using ..

18/Jun/2020 20:30:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 24496
**Not Found: /NONE**
[18/Jun/2020 20:30:03] "GET /NONE HTTP/1.1" **404 2180**

```js
app Views.py
def index(request):
    ########
    ndtvlist = "a list"
    toilist = "a list"

    context={'ndtvlist':ndtvlist,'toilist':toilist}
    return render(request,'news/index.html', context)

proj Urls.py
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('news/',include('news.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

App urls.py
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('market/',views.market,name='market'),
    path('world/',views.world,name='world'),
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light techfont">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
          <a class="navbar-brand bigbrand" href="{% url 'index' %}">TopNews</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'news:market' %}">Market</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'news:world' %}">World</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: `proj Urls.py` and `App urls.py` both contains `path('',views.index,name='index')` here which view you are referring to ? project level or app level ? so I guess that might be causing error ? If you have your index page defined in an app then your main `project level url` should contain `path('',include('project.urls'),name='index'),` and your `app level url` should contain `path('',views.index,name='index')`. Le me know if this works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot to solve the problem, i spot a way to trigger it, it happen everytime an url has a path like:

'your_project'/urls.py

```
   path('/', include('home.urls')),
```

this added / always trigger this problem.

---

The only way i could solve was with a hacky fix. Simply give Django what it is seeking for :p

'your_project'/urls.py

```
def none_fix(request):
   return render(request,'home/home.html')
urlpatterns = [
    path('None', none_fix)]
```

I don't know if there is a clean way to fix it, and i don´t like the solution. This error might spot a broken code i didn´t find yet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was contains with **broken images** with **url('None')**.
You may try to find 'None' value in your Website, if you couldn't find it continue search in DevTools > Network page